# Bad position after loading fabric.js JSON

Tags: javascript, json, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Once I load JSON from a database, the position of some objects is (0,0) even if in JSON the `top` and `left` properties have values other than 0.
I have a custom class which has additional properties from `MyElement` object:

```
var MyElement = {
    contextMenu: ['delete'],
    toObject() {
        return {
            contextMenu: this.contextMenu
        };
    }
};
var MyImage = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image, MyElement, {
    type: 'MyImage',

    toObject(propertiesToInclude) {
        return this.callSuper('toObject', Object.assign(propertiesToInclude, MyElement.toObject.apply(this)));
    }
});

MyImage.fromURL = function(url, callback, imgOptions) {
    fabric.util.loadImage(url, function(img) {
        callback && callback(new MyImage(img, imgOptions));
    }, null, imgOptions && imgOptions.crossOrigin);
};

fabric.MyImage = MyImage;

fabric.MyImage.fromObject = function(object, callback) {
    fabric.util.loadImage(object.src, function(img) {
        callback && callback(new fabric.MyImage(img, object));
    });
};
```

and the JSON in database is here: [JSON represantation of MyImage](https://jsonblob.com/2c645f44-6741-11e7-a38a-738817e44498)

And after loading this JSON by: `canvas.loadFromJSON(data, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));` the MyImage is displayed at (0,0) instead of `top = 191` and `left = 271` even when the Object representation displayed by `console.log(instanceOfMyImage)` has right values for `top` and `left`. Why? Does the canvas render the object earlier than the properites are set? But the image is displayed so the properities are set... 
I noticed that instance of `fabric.Image` works well. Where is the error in my implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution and a mistake in my code. I need to write an `initialize` method with the same signature as in `fabric.Image` and it works. Below the missing code:

```
initialize: function(element, options, callback) {
        this.callSuper('initialize', options);
        this._initElement(element, options, callback);
    },
```